# What software is there to manage GPS tracks on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, gps, garmin

I recently bought a GpsMap from Garmin and use it to track my daily comute (bike) and (less frequent) hikes.

So far I have to bootcamp into XP do manage those tracks.

what would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macauley prompted me to seach garmin's webiste, once again.

To my surprise I found that Garmin has releases "BaseCamp". I was able to extract to the mac, then export and visualize my cycling tracks from our vaccation (Elba, Italy) in Google Earth.

### [BaseCamp for Mac software version 2.0.1](https://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=4449#Instruct)

Answer (score 2):

Garmin Roadtrip for the Mac allows you to download tracks from you Garmin GPS (assuming it is USB).  You can find it at http://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=4332

Once you get the tracks off of your GPS using Garmin Roadtrip, you can export KML files and open them in [Google Earth for the Mac](http://earth.google.com/)  Another program you might find useful is [Trail Runner](http://trailrunnerx.com/).  It has the ability to overlay tracks on topographical maps which I like for looking at hiking/running tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Glad BaseCamp works for you, if you're interested, [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html) is also a pretty nice open source multi-platform app that does all kinds of GPS track/route/waypoint translation with both GUI and CLI interfaces. I'm using it to add traces to [OpenStreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) by converting my Magelland tracks to GPX and I'm also creating a catalog of KML files.